# Close Bootstrap dropdown containing active Select2 element on blur

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a case where two clicks are required to close a Bootstrap dropdown. I need both to close when a click occurs outside the dropdown, say on another dropdown button.

The same thing probably occurs with a standard select element, but this is my particular scenario. I've tried invoking `dropdown('close')` on click of the various Select2 elements with no success.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/PwNpB/15

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn  dropdown-toggle">
        Button <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
    </span>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <select id="e1">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what browser are you experiencing this issue? I've tested in Safari 6.0.2 and Chrome 26.0.1410.43 and it seems to be working properly.

Comment: It looks like the select2 is causing this. No controls are getting focus until you close the form. Unfortunatelly the control doesn't have a Close event.

Comment: I work mostly in Firefox on Win7. However, we're experiencing the same problem in other browsers as well. I'm seeing two clicks required in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this workaround:

```
// initialize Select2 
$("#e1").select2().on('open', function () {
    $('#select2-drop-mask')
       .height($(window).height())
       .width($(window).width())
       .css('opacity', .1);
});


$(document).on('mousedown', '#select2-drop-mask', function () {
    $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
});
```

[SEE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/40/)

Comment: That would seem to do the trick. It's nice and simple, too. Thank you very much. I'll do some cross-browser testing tomorrow.

Comment: Not trying to take away from this solution, but this also raises the `0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange]` error in Firefox described below. @roasted why do you set the height and width for `#select-drop-mask` yourself? I thought that is what select2 is doing itself already in [_makeMaskCss](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L1178)? Is the opacity for demonstrational purposes?

Comment: I have applied the mousedown function (without the expanded Select2 initializer) to my situation and it's working well. I get no errors in IE9, Firefox or Chrome. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/42/ shows that at least in the isolated testcase (now w/o the `open` event listener) the Firefox error persists - which only makes sense, I'm just mentioning it for the sake of completeness. Glad this is working for you! Those timeouts to handle the Firefox error felt yucky and this is the better solution for sure.

Comment: @A. Wolff: Excellent answer. Works perfect in all browsers except IE8+  http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/75/

On clicking the select2 dropdown the bootstrap dropdown disappears. I have set stopPropagation for the element with dropdown-menu class. Still I think in select2.js file, the stopPropagation() and preventDefault() at line numbers 1304 and 1305 causing this issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Select2 plugin. You should ask to them how could it be fixed. For example, here upgrading to select2 3.4.5 fix this bug, but some other appear which seems not related to code posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/77/show/

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm facing similar issue but I do not use Bootstrap and if I remove it from fiddle mentioned in your answer, even that does not works. **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/102/)**.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not really familiar with either twitter-bootstrap or select2 (and not quite fluent in JavaScript either), I noticed that select2 inserts an element called `#select2-drop-mask` which captures the `mousedown`- and `touchstart`-events and handles the closing of the select2-dropdown:

```
mask.bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    var dropdown = $("#select2-drop"), self;
    if (dropdown.length > 0) {
        self=dropdown.data("select2");
        if (self.opts.selectOnBlur) {
            self.selectHighlighted({noFocus: true});
        }
        self.close();
    }
});
```

If we attach those same events (a simple `click` won't work) to the `document` and make sure that the clicked element actually is `#select2-drop-mask` (otherwise bootstrap-tooltips '[toggle](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js#L41)' would be called twice), things seem to behave like you want them to – the twitter-bootstrap dropdown is closed whenever something outside of the select2-element is clicked:

```
function closeBootstrapDropdown() {
    if ($(event.target).is('#select2-drop-mask')) {
        // toggle the twitter-bootstrap dropdown
        $('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    }
}

$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', closeBootstrapDropdown);
```

Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/3/ – while this seems to work, it still feels slightly dirty to me, so I hope someone with some real understanding of what's happening here and why will chime in.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your fiddle still requires two clicks on the area around the dropdown to get it to completely close. It behaves as my example does. Am I missing something? I'm in Firefox on Win7.

Comment: I see what you're saying; I only tested in Chrome up to now – could you verify the behavior there so that we're clear that this is how you want things to work cross-browser? Will look into it again after work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/9/ seems to work in Firefox, but select2 throws an error (as opposed to Chrome) related to (with what I can make of a quick search) focussing a hidden input-field.

Comment: I've managed to eliminate the error by changing dropdown('toggle') to fadeOut(), but then the button is rendered inoperable. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/PwNpB/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/18/ (not by me, I just stumbled across this) works for me in lates Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac - it uses a timeout to delay the hiding of the bootstrap-dropdown, which prevents the Firefox error. Sorry for the ignorant testing, can't connect to my Windows box at work right now.

Comment: I also came across these select2 [github](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/542) [issues](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/246) and thus gave select2s 'close'-event a shot; the behavior differs to my original "answer" as in that the bootstrap-dropdown won't stay open after a select2-option has been changed: http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/22/ - this triggers the same bug in Firefox though. http://jsfiddle.net/PwNpB/41/ incorporates the timeout-workaround mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I think those are also my attempts at modifying your answer. They all tended to cause other issues with the multi-select inside my dropdown. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: No problem! (btw., 22 and 41 were by myself as far as I recall :))

Comment: More helpful than accepted answer... Thanks +1.   

Setting `$('.select2-drop-mask ').css('height','100%'); })` on `"select2-open` callback solved problem in my case